# Http Fallback on RxJava

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I have two http services that can retrieve data.

1. Cache Backend
2. Real Backend

Most of the time, Real backend will get the results within a second. In some 10% cases, its taking more than 1 second.

I am looking for an RxJava operator that does the following.

Fire the query to Real Backend.
if we didn't get the onNext within 1 second, I want it to fire to Cache Backend.

If the real backend took more than a second, we will get items emitted in onNext from both cache and real backend.

What's the right operator to use here?

**MergeDelayError Operator**
     If I use this operator, it will always fire to cache backend as well,  which is unnecessary if the real backend is fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try #2: cache.[takeUntil](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#takeUntil(rx.Observable)) + [merge](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#merge(rx.Observable))

```
    Observable<String> cache = Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .map(new Function<Long, String>() {
        public String apply(Long t) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Invoking cached");
            return "cached";
        }
    });

    Observable<String> original = Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .map(new Function<Long, String>() {
            public String apply(Long t) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Invoking original");
                return "originalBackend";
            }
        });

    Observable<String> originalOnce = original.cache();
    Observable<String> result = cache.takeUntil(originalOnce).mergeWith(originalOnce);

    result.subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
        public void accept(String result) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: public final Observable<T> timeout(long timeout,
                    java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit timeUnit,
                    Observable<? extends T> other)

can accomplish executing an observable after a specified timeout. But it will miss the onNext of the real backend. I couldn't get exactly what you mentioned by Timeout+onErrorReturn

Comment: @nizam.sp so what you would like the construct to do is in timeout case to emit 2 events: one caching and the next after a while backend update?